# Google Sheet Script apparently not returning a number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing my first custom function in Google Script. All works well in debug, my code runs (apparently) perfectly.

There's a function already written (`CONVERT_RACETIME_TO_SECONDS`) which accepts a particularly formatted string and then returns a number of seconds.

This function should then take two ranges and divide the highest of the second range by the lowest of first range.

```
  /**
   * A function that takes two ranges of values and returns a single value.
   * Returns the percentage of the maximum of the second range over the minimum of the first range.
   * this is equal to max(secondrange)/min(firstrange)
   *
   * @param {Array} fast The Range of fastest times  
   * @param {Array} slow The Range of slowest times
   * @return The calculated ratio.
   * @customfunction
   */
  function SLOWEST_RATIO(fast, slow) {
      if (!(fast instanceof Array) || !(slow instanceof Array) ) {
      throw 'Invalid: range input required';
    }

    var fastest = Math.min.apply(null, fast.map(CONVERT_RACETIME_TO_SECONDS));
    var slowest = Math.max.apply(null, slow.map(CONVERT_RACETIME_TO_SECONDS));
    var ratio = slowest/fastest;

    var ratiotype = typeof ratio; 

    if (!(ratiotype == 'number')) {
      throw 'Invalid: ratiotype is ' + ratiotype;
    }

    return ratio; 
  }

function test_slowest_ratio() {
  var fastest = ['21:03.55','21:43.83','22:41.31','23:32.44'];
  var slowest = ['31:11.29','31:19.18','33:05.22','28:17.76'];

  var ratio = SLOWEST_RATIO(fastest, slowest);

  Logger.log('Ratio should be a non-zero number: ' + ratio + ' (is ' + (typeof ratio) + ')');
}
```

It tests, using the second function, perfectly.

> [15-08-26 17:42:04:396 BST] Starting execution [15-08-26 17:42:04:403
>   BST] Logger.log([Ratio should be a non-zero number: 1.5711447904712912
>   (is number), []]) [0 seconds] [15-08-26 17:42:04:404 BST] Execution
>   succeeded [0.002 seconds total runtime]

But when I call from a spreadsheet with the exact same values, but in cells, Sheets gives me an error: *"Error: Result was not a number"*

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and Google app-script does not provide a way to 'force' a return type to number for a custom function.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48537737/594322) answer gets close but return type is an array, not a number.

The answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690712/google-scripts-returning-not-a-number) is correct but no examples for how to coerce the correct type for the return value.

This [link](https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls) has examples of converting Javascript strings into numbers and lists some of the pitfalls.

In order to 'force' the return to a number, add `return Number(ratio);` to the function:

```
  function SLOWEST_RATIO(fast, slow) {
      if (!(fast instanceof Array) || !(slow instanceof Array) ) {
      throw 'Invalid: range input required';
    }

    var fastest = Math.min.apply(null, fast.map(CONVERT_RACETIME_TO_SECONDS));
    var slowest = Math.max.apply(null, slow.map(CONVERT_RACETIME_TO_SECONDS));
    var ratio = slowest/fastest;

    var ratiotype = typeof ratio; 

    if (!(ratiotype == 'number')) {
      throw 'Invalid: ratiotype is ' + ratiotype;
    }

    return Number(ratio); 
  }
```

See my [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48652194/google-sheets-custom-function-error-result-was-not-a-number/48652195#48652195) for a similar issue.