# Google sheets custom function error "Result was not a number"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a Google Sheets Apps Script custom function that produces the error: *"Result was not a number"*. The value returned from the custom function although a number is not being treated as a number regardless of the 'format' applied to the cell. The calculated values cannot then be used in other built-in functions such as SUM().

Similar questions have been asked, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537313/custom-function-doesnt-work-with-arrayformula), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690712/google-scripts-returning-not-a-number), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232191/google-sheet-script-apparently-not-returning-a-number) (and probably others...) but don't explain how to change the return type.

The google apps-script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#data_types) for DataTypes isn't clear how to "force" your custom function to a particular return type.

Link to example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PlLGhj-uZmHO1LH3BuRaPc8Ko-cL8Z1Q1-0lV5oFyMs/edit?usp=sharing) with script.

Here is the function i'm having trouble with (note getCell() not included below):

```
/**
 Sum all transactions across sheets that match category and date range.

 @param category_name The category to filter on
 @param date_min Minimum date in range to filter
 @param date_max Maximum Date in range to filter
 @param [time] Optional update time/date
 @return The sum of transactions that match input criteria
 @customfunction
 */
function sumCategory(category_name, date_min, date_max, time) {      
  var date_min = new Date(date_min);
  var date_max = new Date(date_max);
  var date_month = date_min.getMonth();
  var date_year = date_min.getYear();

  var sheets = ['Account1', 'Account2'];

  var column_name = { 
    Date:   "Date",
    Category: "Category",
    Amount: "Amount"
  };

  var msg = "";
  var sum = 0.0;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Number of seconds before the cache expires.
  var cache_time = 120;

  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();

  // Build the cache key with requested category_year_month
  var cache_key = category_name + '_' + date_year.toString() + '_' + date_month.toString();

  // If we have this category cached, then return it...
  var cached = cache.get(cache_key);
  if (cached != null) {
    return cached;
  }

  // Category sum for cache
  var cat_sum = { }; 

  // Loop through all sheets, and all transactions building the category sum cache
  for(var x = 0; x < sheets.length; x++){  
    var s = sheets[x];
    //Browser.msgBox("Working on sheet: " + s);
    var cur_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(s);

    // Get data range for whole sheet 
    var data =  cur_sheet.getDataRange();
    var num_rows = data.getNumRows();
    var num_cols = data.getNumColumns();

    // Loop through all rows in this sheet
    for(var i = 2; i < num_rows; i++){
      var xdate = new Date(getCell(column_name.Date, i, data));
      var cat = getCell(column_name.Category, i, data);
      var amount = getCell(column_name.Amount, i, data);

      // If the transaction category is empty, set to 'Uncategorized'
      if(!cat){
        cat = "Uncategorized";
      }
      var xkey = cat + '_' + xdate.getYear().toString() + '_' + xdate.getMonth().toString();

      // Check if we have not already stored this category
      if(!cat_sum.hasOwnProperty(xkey)){
        // initialize
        cat_sum[xkey] = 0.0;
      }
      cat_sum[xkey] = cat_sum[xkey] + parseFloat(amount);

    }// end loop rows
  }// end loop sheets

  // Build cache
  for (var key in cat_sum){
    //console.log( key, dict[key] );
    cache.put(key, cat_sum[key], cache_time);
  }

  // If category not found... set to 0.
  if(!cat_sum[cache_key]){
    cat_sum[cache_key] = 0.0;
    cache.put(cache_key, 0.0, cache_time);
  }

  var return_value = cat_sum[cache_key];

  // Return the requested category sum
  return return_value;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without 'correct' or helpful answer? Why the linked question were not helpful to you?

Comment: Sorry... "correct" maybe isn't the right word to use. None of the answers linked to show how to force the return type to a Number (or Array) or other type or explain how to.

Comment: Please add the formula that you tried.

Comment: @ruben, I tried several things to get the return type to a number before getting the answer below. The only way I could force the return type to a number was to use `return Number(return_value);` The other methods I tried that didn't work were to set the cell format to 'Number' or 'Currency', and in the apps-script even `return parseFloat(return-value);` did not work for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript and Google apps-script does not provide a way to 'force' a return type to number for a custom function.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48537737/594322) answer gets close but return type is an array, not a number.

The answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690712/google-scripts-returning-not-a-number) is correct but no examples for how to coerce the correct type for the return value.

This [link](https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls) has examples of converting Javascript strings into numbers and lists some of the pitfalls.

In order to 'force' the return to a number, 
add `return Number(cached);` and
`return Number(return_value);` to the function.

Example [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PlLGhj-uZmHO1LH3BuRaPc8Ko-cL8Z1Q1-0lV5oFyMs/edit?usp=sharing) with script has been updated to return a number.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tx25zqpc/) is JSFiddle with script code.

Comment: example sheet's script is not accessible.

Comment: @YusufK  Thanks for letting me know! I guess the script is not accessible by default. I need to "publish" as an "add on". I'll let you know when that is complete...

Comment: @YusufK. I'm having trouble "publishing" the code, Google makes it extremely hard... I added JSFiddle link with code to answer above if you didn't notice. Thanks!