# Custom function doesn't work with ArrayFormula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i followed the post
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
    return input * 2;
}
```

and copied the very simple DOUBLE function into my app-script.

```
=double(A1)
```

is working and double my integer in 'A1'
But when i filled column A with values, like

```
A1 = 2
A2 = 3
A3 = 4
....
```

And in B1 cell, i run

```
=arrayformula(double(A1:A))
```

it returned error "Result was not a number", #NUM!

I am not sure what goes wrong. Could any app-script gurus helps?

Thanks

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this answer?

- For example, when `=DOUBLE(A1)` is used, the value of `input` of `DOUBLE(input)` is retrieved as a number or a string (in your case, it's a number.).
- For example, when `=DOUBLE(A1:B1)` is used, the values of `input` of `DOUBLE(input)` are retrieved as 2 dimensional array.

It is required to calculate after it confirmed whether `input` is array. The modification which reflected above is as follows.

#### From :

```
return input * 2;
```

#### To :

```
return Array.isArray(input) ? input.map(function(e){return e.map(function(f){return f * 2})}) : input * 2;
```

#### Note :

When the above modified sample is written using "if" and "for loop", it becomes as follows.

```
if (Array.isArray(input)) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
      temp.push(input[i][j] * 2);
    }
    result.push(temp);
  }
  return result;
} else {
  return input * 2;
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike and that's except what I want!

Comment: @Weilies I'm glad your problem was solved. Thank you, too.