# How to make a relative cell reference in a function reference within the setFormula() method?

Tags: methods, google-apps-script, google-sheets, reference, array-formulas

The code below is part of a script. It simply multiplies a value in the C-range with a value in the D-range with a price that is calculated with the function calculatePrice. The function takes a parameter (a label found in the B-Range) upon which is loops through an object to find a matching price. All of that works, but cell B2 should be B3 in the next line, B4 in the line after that etc. How do I get this to work in this formula? I have tried B2:B but that does not work. Help is much appreciated.

```
sheet.getRange(2,5).setFormula('=ArrayFormula(if(not(isblank($C$2:$C)),$C$2:$C*$D$2:$D*calculatePrice(b2)," "))');
```

Comment: I have tried to use index() by omitting the row like so index(B2:B, ,1). This works in a regular spreadsheet, but seems to fail in the context of my formula. Does anyone know why that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code instead:

```
sheet.getRange(2,5).setFormula('=ArrayFormula(if(not(isblank(C2:C)),C2:C*D2:D*calculatePriceArray(B2:B)," "))');
```

As you may notice, your function "calculatePrice" was wrapped by "calculatePriceArray":

```
function calculatePriceArray(input) {
  return Array.isArray(input) ? 
    input.map( function(e) {
      return e.map( function(f){
        return calculatePrice(f);
      })
    }) : 
  calculatePrice(input);
}
```

because we want to return an array.
Really we have used the [known solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537313/custom-function-doesnt-work-with-arrayformula) here.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I am new at this stuff, and this helps a lot to gain better insight and advance my learning process. In my search for an answer, I had seen the known solution but apparently haven't recognized it as a solution applicable to me too. I haven't fully understood it still, but now that I know it works, I am going to study it further.  Thanks again.